# Unable to access current millisecond time in scala using java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

Tags: scala

When I use below code in scala I get a runtime exception :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"

```
object Driver {

    def main(args:Array[String]) = {

      java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

}
```

But when I remove java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(); the main method is found.

Why is this ?

Comment: Also its in System.currentTimeMillis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the equal sign!

That's causing Scala to infer the return type of `main` to be `Long` (Scala) / `long` (at the JVM level). When you remove it, it infers `Unit` / `void`. Likewise when you remove the call to `currentTimeMillis`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the time you can use `compat.Platform.currentTime`

also your object should be

```
object Driver {

    def main(args:Array[String]){

      java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {` is the exact signature for `main()`. Removing `=` seems also a solution, but less error-prone.